# How to get first AND last element of tuple at the same time

Tags: python, indexing, tuples, slice

I need to get the first and last dimension of an numpy.ndarray of arbitrary size.

If I have `shape(A) = (3,4,4,4,4,4,4,3)`
my first Idea would be to do `result = shape(A)[0,-1]` but that doesn't seem to work with tuples, why not ??

Is there a neater way of doing this than

```
s=shape(A)
result=(s[0], s[-1])
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't know what's wrong about

```
(s[0], s[-1])
```

A different option is to use `operator.itemgetter()`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
itemgetter(0, -1)(s)
```

I don't think this is any better, though.  (It might be slightly faster if you don't count the time needed to instantiate the `itemgetter` instance, which can be reused if this operation is needed often.)

Comment: I was just wondering, because I haven't worked with tuples that much so far.
Thanks, I'm going to accept your answer as soon as I can (~8 minutes :))

Answer (score 6):

```
s = (3,4,4,4,4,4,4,3)
result = s[0], s[-1]
```

Answer (score 5):

Came across this late; however, just to add a non indexed approach as previously mentioned.

Tuple unpacking can be easily be applied to acquire the first and last elements. Note: The below code is utilizing the special asterisk '*' syntax which returns a list of the middle section, having a and c storing the first and last values.

Ex.

```
A= (3,4,4,4,4,4,4,3)
a, *b, c = A
print((a, c))
```

Output
(3, 3)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using numpy array, then you may do that

```
s = numpy.array([3,4,4,4,4,4,4,3])
result = s[[0,-1]]
```

where `[0,-1]` is the index of the first and last element. It also allow more complex extraction such as `s[2:4]`

Comment: yes, but shape does not return a np.array.
The strange thing is, that the `s[2:4]` access even is possible for a tuple, but `s[0, -1]` is not